# How to get the sum of the values from different nodes in XML file using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I am new to XSLT, and have no idea to deal with it.
My XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<books>
  <book>
    <title type="fiction">CS115</title>
    <authors>Adams</authors>
    <price>12.0</price>
  </book>
  <book>
    <title type="fiction">CS205</title>
    <authors>Dykes</authors>
    <price>50.2</price>
  </book>
  <book>
    <title type="nonfiction">CS255</title>
    <authors>Brunner,Computer</authors>
    <price>11.5</price>
  </book>
   <book>
    <title type="nonfiction">CS118</title>
    <authors>Adams,Bououss</authors>    
    <price>20.0</price>
  </book>
   <book>
    <title type="fiction">The Hobbit</title>
    <authors>J.R.R. Tolkien</authors>    
    <price>25.99</price>
  </book>
</books>
```

I wanna calculate the total price of the books whose price is less than 30 and **title/@type** is fiction.

Answer (score 3):

Start with learning some XPath: `/books/book` selects all `book` elements, `/books/book[title/@type = 'fiction']` those with the title's type attribute being fiction, `/books/book[title/@type = 'fiction' and price < 30]` adds the constraints about the price, finally `sum(/books/book[title/@type = 'fiction' and price < 30]/price)` computes the sum.

Inside of XSLT code you need to escape the `<`: `<xsl:value-of select="sum(/books/book[title/@type = 'fiction' and price &lt; 30]/price)"/>`.

Comment: OMG, is that easy? i tried some ways like to define a globe variable and then add the price, but seems xslt dont allows to do so...